# How to avoid future locks in MS-DOS

Tags: networking, ms-dos, lock

I'm running a *legacy application* in `MS-DOS 6.22`, which writes and reads some files in a folder. This folder is shared in my LAN and I'm trying to read these files, but I can't because these files are locked by this legacy application.

I'm running `SHARE.EXE` in my `config.sys` with:

```
INSTALL=C:\DOS\SHARE.EXE /L:1 /F:4096
```

This command doesn't work with `/L:0`, which I thought would disable filelocking.

Is there a way to prevent/disable filelocking before starting this application? Or some way to read a locked file in `MS-DOS`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a way to sidestep this without intimate knowledge of this program and hacking it.  I do wonder if you could run this under a 32-bit version of Windows with the NTVDM (like XP) and access concurrently that way.

Comment: *Is there a way to prevent/disable filelocking before starting this application?* Of course you can. But the application will fail while starting or while trying to access the file with exclusive lock. *some way to read a locked file in MS-DOS?* Try to put this file onto mapped network drive.

Comment: @LawrenceC I didn't try it. This application has some kind of license which takes HDD serial number... So I cannot run in another computer neither in a VM like VMware or VirtualBox... I could format and install WinXP directly in that machine, but I'm not sure if I will lost that license...

Comment: @Akina, Could you guide me in how to disable file locking without disabling file sharing? I want to give it a shot. This file is already in a mapped network drive, I'm trying to access in my Windows 10.

Comment: How are you using LAN in MS-DOS 6.22?

Comment: @harrymc, I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/j_helmig/dosservr.htm) then, in my windows 10: `net use F:\ \\servername\publicfolder`